# Select Only Max 3 Rows From The Same User - MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's say there are two tables:

Table "photos" with columns:

```
id,
title,
path,
user_id
```

And table "users" with columns:

```
id
username
```

What I want to do is select let's say 30 photos from the "photos" table but with condition that there are at most 3 photos from the same user in the fetched result set. So far I have this query:

```
SELECT p.*, u.username FROM photos AS p 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = p.user_id 
ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 30;
```

How to create a WHERE clause to achieve max. 3 rows from the same user in the fetched result set?

EDIT: I'm using MySQL 5.1.33

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here is a "clever" way to do it:

```
SELECT u.username, p1.* FROM photos AS p1
 INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id=p1.user_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN photos AS p2 ON p2.user_id=p1.user_id and p2.id <= p1.id
 GROUP BY p1.id
 HAVING COUNT(p2.id) <= 3
 LIMIT 30;
```

Having said that, be weary of "clever" code. It makes you feel good in the near term but maintenance can be painful.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT p.*, u.username 
FROM photos AS p 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = p.user_id 
WHERE p.id in (
 SELECT id  
 FROM photos p
 WHERE user_id  = p.user_id 
 LIMIT 3
)
ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 30;
```

Comment: No TOP in MySQL :( Try again.

Comment: Would that work in MySQL? I tried the query in phpmyadmin and I got an error, I think "top" is not supported by MySQL.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I'm using MySQL 5.1.33 and it doesn't support LIMIT clause in SELECT subqueries.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at [this technique](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/).  Your where clause would be 
    WHERE row_number <3

and then
    limit 30

Answer (score 1):

Hand translated from T-SQL, so untested on MySQL.

```
SELECT p.*, u.username
FROM photos AS p
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE p.id IN (
 SELECT p1.id
 FROM photos p1
 JOIN photos p2
 ON p1.user_id = IFNULL( p2.user_id, p1.user_id )
 AND p1.id <= IFNULL( p2.id, p1.id )
 GROUP BY p1.id
 HAVING COUNT(*) < 4
)
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: This returns an empty result set (and there are rows in the table that fulfill the condition).

Comment: Worked for me on 5.0.41.  What data type are the ids?

Comment: INT, but I have already used Asaph's query. Thanks anyways :)